# Status Bar in for loop

Tags: sql, r, progress-bar, rsqlite

I was trying to create a status bar in my for loop, but the status remains at 0%. I'm not sure what the issue could be.

```
  n <- length(unique(mu_ut$AnimalID))
  pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = n, style = 3)
  for(i in unique(mu_ut$AnimalID)){ 
     AnID <- paste("AnID", i, sep = ".")
     assign(AnID, mu_ut[mu_ut$AnimalID == i,])
     dbWriteTable(conn = db, name = AnID, value = mu_ut[mu_ut$AnimalID == i,], 
                  field.types = c(DateAndTime = "DATETIME", 
                                  AnimalID = "CHAR",
                                  Species = "CHAR",
                                  Sex = "CHAR",
                                  CurrentCohort = "CHAR",
                                  BirthYear = "DATE",
                                  CaptureUnit = "CHAR",
                                  CaptureSubunit = "CHAR",
                                  CaptureArea = "CHAR"), overwrite = TRUE)
  Sys.sleep(1)
  setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
  }
```

Is it a problem with the "i" argument in the setTxtProgressBar function?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What if you tried `for(i 1:n)` instead and adjusted the rest of the code accordingly, i.e. define `j <- unique(mu_ut$AnimalID)[i]`?

Comment: So should I replace the `mu_ut[mu_ut$AnimalID == i,]` with "j" in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `setTxtProgressBar` needs its value to be in the sequence `min=0` to `max=n`, as set in your `txtProgressBar`. Since `i` is really one of the unique values within `mu_ut$AnimalID`, even if it is an integer, it is not clear that it is *also* in the range `0:n`.

Try this.

```r
  ids <- unique(mu_ut$AnimalID)
  pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = length(ids), style = 3)
  for (ind in seq_along(ids)) { 
     id <- ids[ind]
     AnID <- paste("AnID", id, sep = ".")
     assign(AnID, mu_ut[mu_ut$AnimalID == id,])
     dbWriteTable(conn = db, name = AnID, value = mu_ut[mu_ut$AnimalID == id,], 
                  field.types = c(DateAndTime = "DATETIME", 
                                  AnimalID = "CHAR",
                                  Species = "CHAR",
                                  Sex = "CHAR",
                                  CurrentCohort = "CHAR",
                                  BirthYear = "DATE",
                                  CaptureUnit = "CHAR",
                                  CaptureSubunit = "CHAR",
                                  CaptureArea = "CHAR"), overwrite = TRUE)
  Sys.sleep(1)
  setTxtProgressBar(pb, ind)
  }
```

(This is very similar to @CareyCaginalp's comment.)